# How to change values of R cells (dataframe) based on a condition for specific rows>?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe,

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want to now apply the following condition on the dataframe for specific indexes only.

- C1 should be equal to 0
- A random number should be less than 0.5

If the above conditions match, I want to change the value of the Cell in C1 and C2 to 1 else do nothing.

I am trying the following: (rowIndex is the specific indexes on which I want to apply the conditions)

```
apply(DF[rowsIndex,], 2, fun)
```

where fun is:

```
fun<- function(x) {
  ifelse(x==0,ifelse(runif(n=1)<0.5,x <- 1,x),x )
  print(x)
}
```

My questions are:

- In my function, How do I apply the conditions to a certain column only i.e C1 (I have tried using DF[rowsIndex,c(1)], but gives an error
- Is there any other approach I can take Since this approach is not giving me any results and the same DF is printed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay in base R:

```
#your dataframe
DF <- data.frame(C1 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
           C2 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
           C3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

fun<- function(x) {
  if(x[1]==0 & runif(n=1)<0.5) {
    x[1:2] <- 1
    }
  
  return(x)
}
#your selection of rows you want to process
rowsIndex <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

#Using MARGIN = 1 applies the function to the rows of a dataframe
#this returns a dataframe containing your selected and processed rows
DF_processed <- t(apply(DF[rowsIndex,], 1, fun))

#replace the selected rows in the original DF by the processed rows
DF[rowsIndex, ] <- DF_processed

print(DF)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. When I run this function, my original Dataframe is unaffected. How do I merge the results with my original dataframe (that has way more rows)

Comment: I edited my answer to include steps necessary to get to your desired outcome. On a site note I recommend you check out TarJae's tidy R approach and in general consider using tidy R methods for your analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(C1, C2), ~ifelse(C1 == 0 & runif(1) < 0.5, 1, .)))
```

```
   C1 C2 C3
1  1  0  0
2  1  1  0
3  1  0  0
4  1  1  0
5  1  0  0
```

Applying it to your function:

```
fun<- function(df, x, y) {
  df %>% 
    mutate(across(c({{x}}, {{y}}), ~ifelse({{x}} == 0 & runif(1) < 0.5, 1, .)))
}

fun(df, C1, C2)
```

```
  C1 C2 C3
1  0  0  0
2  1  1  0
3  0  0  0
4  1  1  0
5  0  0  0
```